psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL: role "testusr" does not exist
I am trying to run in Postgres DB with Kubernetes and using configmap.yaml, service.yaml, statefulset.yaml and volumn yaml.
But when I run below command I get below error.

Command: kubectl exec -it postgres-0 -- psql -U testusr
Error: psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "testusr" does not exist command terminated with exit code 2

Additional info : Im testing this on Mac. not sure if my paths are not correct.
Below is the ss of kubectl.

files are like below.
Configmap.yaml


apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-config
  labels:
    app: postgres
data:
  POSTGRES_DB: testdb
  POSTGRES_USER: testusr
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: testusr



service.yaml


apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  selector:
    app: postgres
  ports:
    - port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
  type: ClusterIP



statefulset.yaml


apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  serviceName: postgres
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-config
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 256Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 512Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: postgres-data
              mountPath: "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: postgres-data
      spec:
        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 5Gi



volume.yaml


apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgres-volume-claim
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi




Is there a Postgres instance that has testusr already created in it?

@AdrianKlaver in config map its mentioned. I was following one tutorial.

That configuration means nothing if testusr has not already been created in the Postgres instance.
